# linux promote program as shell command

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to add some program as shell command. For example, instead of typing "/usr/sbin/postfix" I would only type "postfix". I don't want to use aliases, because they are restricted to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/sbin` to the path (for adding all binaries under that directory) or symlink them under `/usr/bin` if you have specific ones (e.g. `ln -s /usr/sbin/postfix /usr/bin/postfix`)